# Evaluating a clinical test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chemometrics

I need to evaluate a test (posterior predictive value) but the test results can change based on certain other independent factors. Let's say my test measures a biochemical value but depending on what room temperature the test is performed the value changes. How can I model this fact in my calculations without running a bunch of tests in different temperatures or something similar?

Comment: Any model for the way the test depends on temperature that doesn't use results from the test run at different temperatures would appear to be pure guesswork.

Comment: What is the test, and why do you want to model the effects of these "other independent factors"?